# Paypal PDT - unable to get transaction ID

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

After a customer pays from Paypal, he can be auto-redirected back to my website with auto-return and pdt features switched on. Everything works fine when the customer waits 10 seconds for the auto-redirect, transaction id is sent via a get, but when the customer chooses to "click here" instead of waiting for 10 seconds for the auto-redirect, the transaction id is not sent.

Anyone knows of a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, are you just trying to display the transaction ID or are you trying to add it in a database or use it for email receipts, etc?

If you're simply trying to display it then PDT is fine.  Otherwise, I'd highly recommend you use IPN instead.  It's very similar except that the data will always be POSTed to it regardless of whether the user makes it back to your site or not, which isn't always guaranteed, even with Auto-Return enabled.

If PDT is all you need, it really should work the same regardless of how they make it back.  I use PDT so rarely, though, that I really haven't tested it much lately.  I'd have to run some tests in the sandbox to see if I can reproduce that and figure out how to make it work how you want.

Let me know, though, because if IPN is the better solution I don't want to waste time messing with PDT.